# Global variable set in the template's header.php is unable to echo in footer.php

Tags: templates

E.g. I set this in header.php in my template:

```
<?php $postidextra = get_the_ID(); ?> 
<?php $sidebar_state = get_post_meta($postidextra , 'rw_sidebar_state', true); ?>
```

And I can echo $sidebar_state in header.php, it's working.

However, when I try to echo this variable from footer.php or page.php it's not working and I need to repeat my code to get the post id and post meta etc. which is repeating and a bad practice.

**Why it's not available if it is just include?**

How to make the variable available in all files across WP template files?

**UPDATE:**

After suggestion to use global variables I am still unable to `echo $sidebar_state;` in footer.php. My code in header.php looks like this:

```
 <?php global $postidextra; ?> 
 <?php $postidextra = get_the_ID(); ?>
 <?php global $sidebar_state; ?>
 <?php $sidebar_state = get_post_meta($postidextra , 'rw_sidebar_state', true); ?>
```

Footer.php looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains footer content and the closing of the
 * #main and #page div elements.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
?>
    </div><!-- #main .wrapper -->
    <footer id="colophon" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="site-info">
            <?php echo $sidebar_state; ?>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

`<?php echo $sidebar_state; ?>` is wokring only in header.php . Any idea what should I change in my code?

Comment: Ever heard of `global` and `$GLOBALS`?

Comment: @kaiser Ever noticed the bold text in my question?

Comment: @kaiser and even if I do `global $sidebar_state;` it's not working. Please, explain who do you mean exactly and how should it be done, instead of downvoting without a reason.

Comment: `global $sidebar_state;` go before you set the var and before using it.

Comment: [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573847/php-global-or-globals) about that topic.

Comment: @G.M. Check my updated question. It's still not working ;(

Comment: @kaiser I have tried what you suggested, but it's not working. Please, check my updated question.

Comment: @G.M. Even if I do something simple like `<?php global $postidextra; ?> <?php $postidextra = "20"; ?>` and `<?php echo $postidextra; ?>` it's still only working in header.php and not in footer.php . Why can't I use the `$postidextra` variable in footer.php if it is set as global in header.php? I am using standard WP template (Twenty Twelve 1.0), that comes with WP.

Comment: @Vickey can you explain what do you mean by that a little further?

Comment: Read my comment: _"before you set the var **and** before using it"_. `<?php global $postidextra; $postidextra = "20"; ?>` and then `<?php global $postidextra; echo $postidextra; ?>`

Comment: Wow, thanks, please, make it as an naswer, so other people can find it useful.

Comment: No need to add it as an answer. As it's an off topic question, it already got three close votes.

Comment: @kaiser Why I see no close votes? Could you explain that to me?

Comment: @kaiser are you a moderator? If yes, please explain to me why I don't see close votes as an author of this question? It should be `close(3)` near the flag link, however I don't see anything. Please, explain that to me. Thank you a lot. This is what I see http://s8.postimg.org/7jwbc4451/close.jpg

Comment: I guess you ain't got enough reputation points to see that. And no, I'm no moderator. IIRC Those have square icons next to their username.

Answer (score 4):

All I need was to use global variable before the declaration **AND** before echoing.

```
<?php global $postidextra; $postidextra = "20"; ?>
```

and then

```
<?php global $postidextra; echo $postidextra; ?>
```

Thanks G.M. for the idea.

Comment: fyi, the reason this is necessary is because the header and footer are included via functions, placing the variable only in scope of each function if it's not globalized within each.

Answer (score 2):

the codex states that you can only use `get_the_id()` in [the Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID)

Comment: Thanks, I think this would be the problem. I will try to go from here and I will let you know.

Comment: Hmm, I have tried `<?php global $postidextra; ?>
 <?php $postidextra = $wp_query->post->ID; ?>` and `<?php echo $postidextra; ?>` is still only working in header.php . and not in footer.php ;(. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @kaiser Even if I do `<?php global $postidextra; ?> <?php $postidextra = "20"; ?>` and `<?php echo $postidextra; ?>` again, it's still only working in header.php and not in footer.php . Why can't I use the `$postidextra` variable in footer.php if it is set as global in header.php? I am using standard WP template (Twenty Twelve 1.0), that comes with WP

Comment: just wondering, what are you trying to achieve? What's that sidebar state that you're trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that a declared global variable in `header.php` cannot be accessed in `footer.php` is because `header.php` and `footer.php` are template-part files that are included in a given template file via `get_header()` and `get_footer()`, respectively.

Each of these template tags is a fancy wrapper for the PHP `include()` function. In PHP, global variables are not passed to included files, and thus cannot be referenced without being redeclared.

The solution is simply to **declare the global variable in `footer.php`** before referencing it.